# error when running python script: "AttributeError: 'EventObject' object has no attribute 'sentence'"

Tags: python, attributeerror

when I run my code, I receive the following error message. I think the fault must lie in a short script that is called upon when I run the main script, because that is the only one in which there is an "EventObject". This is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'EventObject' object has no attribute 'sentence'
```

This is the code from the short script:

```
class AnnotationsObject:

def __init__(self):
    self.eventlist = []
    self.entitylist = []
    self.polaritytriggerslist = []


class EventObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.eventtext = []
        self.polarity = None
        self.sameclause = False

class EntityObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entitytype = None
        self.entitytext = []
        self.polarity = []
        self.metonymy = False

class PolarityTriggersObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = []
        self.polarity = []
        self.target = []
        self.id = None
        self.irony = []
        self.eventrelationpolarity = []
        self.span = []
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Edit: This is the piece of code which calls on "EventObject" and the "sentence"-attribute

```
def write_annotations_eventpolarity(allAnnotationsDict, annotatornames, outfilefolder):
alleventsdict = get_all_events(allAnnotationsDict)
'''
Gets, for every unique event (alleventslist), its polarity given by each annotator
'''
with open(os.path.join(outfilefolder,'annotations_eventpolarity.csv'), 'w') as csvfile:
    outfilewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    outfilewriter.writerow(['Document', 'Event'] + [a for a in annotatornames] + ['Sentence', 'Sentence without event'])
    for documentname, annotatordict in allAnnotationsDict.items():
        #Get a list of all events per document, consider the first annotator in the dict, as the events are the same for each annotator.
        allevents = alleventsdict[documentname][annotatornames[0]]
        alleventstrings = ['+'.join(x.eventtext) for x in allevents] #Events can be stored as lists of two non-consecutive spans
        alleventsentences = [x.sentence for x in allevents]
        alleventsentenceswithoutevent = [x.sentencewithoutevent for x in allevents]
        seen = []
        for eventText, eventSent, eventSentWith in zip(alleventstrings, alleventsentences, alleventsentenceswithoutevent):
            rowelements = [] #Rowelements will be written to output file
            rowelements.append(documentname)
            rowelements.append(eventText)
            for a in annotatornames:
                pol = []
                eventobjectslist = alleventsdict[documentname][a]
                for eveobj in eventobjectslist:
                    found = False
                    if '+'.join(eveobj.eventtext) == eventText and eveobj.sentence == eventSent:
                        if eveobj.polarity == None:
                            pol.append('None')
                        else:
                            pol.append(eveobj.polarity)
                        found = True
                    else:
                        continue
                    if not found:
                        print('Warning: event\t{0}\t{1}\tfrom annotator {2} not found in alleventslist.'.format(eveobj.eventtext, documentname, a))
                        warnings.append('Write annotations for event polarities: event\t{0}\t{1}\tfrom annotator {2} not found in alleventslist.'.format(eveobj.eventtext, documentname, a))
                if len(pol) > 1 and 'None' in pol: #Event polarity can be 'None' if the event is part of a linked event span and its polarity was added to the other part
                    indx_none = pol.index('None') #Remove 'None' polarities
                    pol.pop(indx_none)
                rowelements.append(','.join(list(set(pol))))
            rowelements.append(eventSent)
            rowelements.append(eventSentWith)
            if not (eventText,eventSent) in seen: #Discard 100% duplicates (i.e. events that are annotated twice in the sentence)
                outfilewriter.writerow(rowelements)
            seen.append((eventText,eventSent))
```

The error seems to occur at `alleventsentences = [x.sentence for x in allevents]`

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: The bit of code you posted can't produce said error. Where is the code that calls upon EventObject.sentence? Eitherway, that's your problem: you're trying to access EventObject.sentence, but it does not exist in the class. That much is clear from the code you've shown us.

Comment: @Kraay89 Hello and thank you for your answer! I have added the piece of code that calls upon EventObject and the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading an uninitialized field from an object.

For example:

```
EventObject e = EventObject()
```

and then

```
print(e.sentence)
```

before

```
e.sentence = "..."
```

Another solution is to initialize the field in the constructor:

```
class EventObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.eventtext = []
        self.polarity = None
        self.sameclause = False
        self.sentence = "..."
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This solved my problem. After this I got the error `AttributeError: 'EventObject' object has no attribute 'sentencewithoutevent'`, but I was able to solve it in the same way. The script works fine now, thank you for your help! I also wanted to let you know that I did vote for your answer, but apparently my reputation isn't high enough for it to change the publicly displayed post score. Nevertheless I will come back to it once my reputation is higher!

Answer (score 0):

```
class EventObject:
def __init__(self):
    self.eventtext = []
    self.polarity = None
    self.sameclause = False
```

You are missing `sentence` here. Something like `self.sentence = None`